# Sentiment prediction Google Sentiment API

Tags: google-api, sentiment-analysis

I am using Google API to predict the sentiment of student for professor, I have already trained a model for it. and I also test it. It works.

But I have about 20 K, data in my hand, it is too much to copt and paste to test it. Do you guys have some ideas can make it easy to run for these 20 k data?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data into a CSV file and upload it to your Google Cloud Storage.
You can upload it via the Google Developers Console, GSUtil or by using Google Cloud Storage API's

The maximum file size for the CSV is 2.5GB, you can find more information on the their developer guide @ [Training Data File Format](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/developer-guide)

- [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
- [Google GSUtil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)
- [Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques)